# Powerapps how to input into a people picker column in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, peoplepicker, powerapps-formula

I have a PowerApps app that has a field that is supposed to feed into a people picker column in SharePoint online.

I have a data card for "Manager Name" ,which is a people picker column in SharePoint, the card contains a combo box.

[image]

---

The Combo box contains this information which allows it to search Office 365 and return a list of users. I can then choose the user from the list.

[image]

---

This is the information for the data card which should feed into the SharePoint column

[image]

I'm not sure what I need to put into "default" and "update" fields which I think is where the issue is arising.

I am fairly new to PowerApps so sorry if this is an obvious question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Combobox is working and you are getting the users just fine, you could trt the following:

**Default**: ThisItem.'Your Column Name'

**Update**:

```
 {
   '@odata.type':"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
   Claims:First(ComboBox4.SelectedItems).Claims,
   DisplayName:First(ComboBox4.SelectedItems).DisplayName,
   Email:First(ComboBox4.SelectedItems).Email
 }
```

Now, you might need to change the combobox **DefaultSelectedItems** conditionally (if the FormMode is New, Edit or View)

**DefaultSelectedItems**

```
Table({
    '@odata.type':"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
    Claims: ThisItem.'Your Column Name'.Claims,
    DisplayName:ThisItem.'Your Column Name'.DisplayName,
    Email:ThisItem.'Your Column Name'.Email   
})
```